# ACTION_SET_ALARM from service on Android 10+

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-10.0

I have an application that has such function as Alarm Clock.
For some people, it is more convenient to use an external Alarm Clock for some reason. So, for such people, I have an option "Use external Alarm Clock".
I used to start [ACTION_SET_ALARM](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock#ACTION_SET_ALARM) from my service before Android 10 like this:

```
...
 
        val intent = Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM).apply {
            putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
            putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, calendar.hourOfDay)
            putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, calendar.minute)
            putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true)
            putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_VIBRATE, appPreferences.alarmVibration)
            ringtone?.let {
                putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_RINGTONE, it)
            }
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        }
        if (intent.resolveActivity(appContext.packageManager) != null) {
            appContext.startActivity(intent)
...
```

Since Android 10, there are some restrictions: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

So, I cannot start activity for enabling external alarms anymore, and it's very annoying.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

For now, I'm thinking about asking users to grant SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission but it seems like a wrong way. Anyway, it doesn't solve all the problems because of restrictions on Android Go.

Comment: "I used to start ACTION_SET_ALARM from my service" -- why is this being done from a service and not from your UI? After all, you have no idea what the user is doing in the foreground from your service, and the user may be very unhappy that you are interrupting them with this alarm clock activity right at that point in time.

Comment: Because when one alarm is fired, I have to schedule next one without starting my application. And I use AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI to prevent interrupting user from what is he doing

Comment: "And I use AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI to prevent interrupting user from what is he doing" -- you are assuming that every alarm clock honors that extra.

Comment: Anyway, it's users choice to decide use this option or not. If their alarm clock on device is working correctly for them, they could choose to enable it. And that they ask for, so I don't want to discuss why I'm doing it. I just want to know if it's possible

Comment: @CommonsWare imagine that somebody uses my app to decide _when_ he wants to wake up, but he has his favorite alarm clock app with blackjack and hookers, and wants to use it for waking him up. ACTION_SET_ALARM has been working for these users for years, and now they are very unhappy because of this restriction

Comment: Personally, I think that the security and safety benefits of blocking background activity starts outweigh that. Regardless, other than your `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` solution, I do not think that you have any other options, other than to disable this particular feature for newer versions of Android.

Answer (score 1):

for android 9 and above you can use android [JobService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService) other then background service as they are more optimized for device and the user, or you can use [Foreground](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) service as regular service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm asking about starting activity, not service
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock#ACTION_SET_ALARM

Comment: did u tried with flags : intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
cant explain it but it resolved my issue of opening app from widget